# using skimage to replace scipy.misc.imread

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

There is a code segment using scipy.misc to read image

```
from scipy import misc
im = misc.imread(self.file_image, True)
```

I would like to know, are there any functions in scikit-image that can replace the above code with the same output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do it in scikit-image.

```
from skimage import io
im = io.imread(self.file_image)
```

However, according to scipy's documentation "imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead."

So the better option is to use imageio to read images. You can install imageio if not already installed by using `pip install imageio`

Comment: Your answer confuses several issues here.  The code snippet you give is correct, but the deprecation is specifically for the `imread` function in SciPy, and does not pertain to `imread` in skimage which is alive and well.  skimage wraps whatever is available on your system, so while it is perfectly fine to switch to imageio (we may default to that in the future as well), we also support matplotlib and others.

Comment: Oh, you are right. The deprecation is only for imread function in scipy, I had a misconception that scikit-image would also default to imageio.imread, hence the recommendation.